# Magento 1.9.2 Onepage Checkout Slow when saving Billing Information

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I am running a `Magento 1.9.2` store for a client and am experiencing major issues with the speed of the standard `Onepage` checkout.

If a user is logged in or checking out as a guest, it takes upwards of 60 seconds to save the user's billing information, even if they are using a saved address. I don't know if it's a processing bottleneck or something deeper in the `Magento` system.

Everything else appears to be working smoothly. To my knowledge there are no extensions running at the checkout point.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Disabled Mage_Rss and Mage_Downloadable observers, which can apparently contribute to speed at checkout
- Truncating the sales_flat_quote... tables which greatly increased speed across the site
- Changed the caching engine to `Cm_Cache_Backend_File` (https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_File)

Any help or insight into how `Magento` handles saving billing information or any corners that could be cut in checkout would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the issue by outright disabling the shipping tracking for DHL, FedEx, etc.

Even though the primary country was not applicable to those services, the system was still querying their webservices and in places erroring out, which was creating the slowdown. If you are not using these services, make sure to disable them outright rather than just unchecking the countries.